# blazor why after login i see nothing?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

im still learning blazor but have some basic probably issue
can someone please tell me why i see logonscreen and after i logged i see only white screen with no content ?

main layout:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject UserService u

@if (u.User != null)
{

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body

        </article>
    </main>
</div>
}
else
{
   <LoginComponent></LoginComponent>
}
```

and logon component is a form and with logon method
with

```
@inject UserService us
```

and on submit:

```
private LoginModel model = new LoginModel();

private  void OnValidSubmit()
{

    try
    {
        us.LoginUser(model);
        StateHasChanged();          
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

and userservice is registered as singelton

```
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<UserService>();
```

and it is simple for now like

```
   public class UserService
{
    public UserModel User ;


    public  void LoginUser(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (model.Username=="xxx")
        {               
            this.User = new UserModel();
            this.User.UserName = model.Username;
            this.User.SurName = "asd'";                             
        }
    }
}
```

thanks alot and regards !

Comment: Your login system is indeed weird (no password, no database, your UserService should not be a singleton because of UserService.User...). I suggest you follow a tutorial for Blazor authentication using the Microsoft authentication system ([Some doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)).

Comment: if it is wasm i see no issues with it to be singelton. will be max one user per   instance. and thanks for comment - i known this blazor auth but this is way for complecated that i need for this one - it will be simple querry from existing table - some internal system so no point of complicating it with ms auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```
us.LoginUser(model);
StateHasChanged();
```

Is called in a child component and so has no effect on parent component refresh.

```
@if (u.User != null)
```

Is not refreshed automatically.

You could declare an event in your UserService like:

```
public class UserService
{
    public UserModel User ;

    public EventHandler OnUserLoggedIn;

    public  void LoginUser(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (model.Username == "xxx")
        {               
            this.User = new UserModel();
            this.User.UserName = model.Username;
            this.User.SurName = "asd'";
            OnUserLoggedIn?.(this, null);
        }
    }
}
```

And in your MainLayout add:

```
@code
{
    protected override void OnInitialize()
    {
        u.OnUserLoggedIn += (_, __) => this.StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

In this way the login action will call StateHasChanged() on MainLayout.
Didn't run the code so maybe there are some little approximations.

Comment: thanks i didnt known that StateHasChanged is not global. i will accept answer  :) regards